# Member is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, asp.net

[ProductContext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw5Ck.png)[Category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq2aC.png)[product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf0Ln.png)I keep getting error code for both `context.Categories.Add(c)` and `context.Prodcuts.Add(p)` that it's inaccessible due to it's protection level. Everything seems correct. Please help me.

```
namespace WingtipToys.Models
{
    public class ProductDatabaseInitializer: DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges <ProductContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ProductContext context)
        {
            GetCategories().ForEach(c => context.Categories.Add(c));
            GetProducts().ForEach(p => context.Products.Add(p));
        }
        private static List<Category> GetCategories()
        {
            var categories = new List<Category>
            {
                new Category
                {
                    CategoryID = 1,
                    CategoryName = "Cars"
                },
                new Category
                {
                    CategoryID = 2,
                    CategoryName = "PLANES"
                },
            };
            return categories;
        }
        private static List<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            var products = new List<Product>
            {
                new Product
                {
                    ProductID = 1,
                    ProductName = "Convertible Car",
                    Description = "This convertible Car is fast!",
                    ImagePath = "carconvert.png",
                    UnitPrice = 22.50,
                    CategoryID = 1
                },
            };
            return products;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code for your `Product` and `Category` classes?

Comment: Could you please provide the error message in full? Also, what access modifiers are used for the members Categories and Products on ProductContext?

Comment: post you code about how `Product` & `Category` are in  `ProductContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put public in front of your Dbset and DbSet if you want to use it like that. Take a look on [Access Modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)
Try this:

```
public DbSet<Category> Categories;
public DbSet<Product> Products;
```